# Any way to verify a service bus trigger to SendGridMessage succeeded before executing code?

Tags: c#, azure, message-queue, azure-functions, sendgrid

I've got an azure function right now that runs on a service bus trigger (queue trigger) and outputs a SendGridMessage. The trick is I need to do some cleanup in my blob storage after the function has successfully sent a sendgrid message but it seems like I have no way of identifying whether or not the function was successful until after it goes out of scope.

I'm currently attempting to push the message that needs to be cleaned up to a cleanup queue and take care of it after the try catch but I think I'm still running into the same problem. The function could succeed and then fail on the SendGrid output and the message would be cleaned up but thrown back into the queue to be reprocessed on this function and fail. Bleh.

**Queue Trigger and Sendgrid Output**

```
[FunctionName("ProcessEmail")]
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("email-queue-jobs", AccessRights.Manage, 
    Connection = "MicroServicesServiceBus")]OutgoingEmail outgoingEmail, TraceWriter log,
    [ServiceBus("email-queue-cleanup", Connection = "MicroServicesServiceBus", 
    EntityType = Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.EntityType.Queue)] IAsyncCollector<OutgoingEmail> cleanupEmailQueue,
    [SendGrid] out SendGridMessage message)
{
    try
    {
        log.Info($"Attempting to send the email {outgoingEmail.Id}");
        message = SendgridHelper.ConvertToSendgridMessage(outgoingEmail);

        log.Info("Successfully sent email:");
        log.Info(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(outgoingEmail));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        message = null;
        throw ex;
    }

    // Add email to the cleanup queue
    log.Info("Sending email to the cleanup queue.");
    cleanupEmailQueue.AddAsync(outgoingEmail).Wait();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by using `ICollector` or `IAsyncCollector`

```
[SendGrid] ICollector<SendGridMessage> messageCollector)
```

and then

```
var message = SendgridHelper.ConvertToSendgridMessage(outgoingEmail);
messageCollector.Add(message);
```

should call `SendGrid` synchronously and throw exception in case of failure.

If you want to use `IAsyncCollector` (as you already do for another binding), be sure to call `FlushAsync` method too:

```
[SendGrid] IAsyncCollector<SendGridMessage> messageCollector)
```

and then

```
var message = SendgridHelper.ConvertToSendgridMessage(outgoingEmail);
await messageCollector.AddAsync(message);
await messageCollector.FlushAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What is the purpose of FlushAsync?

Comment: `FlushAsync` forces the binding to send the data